# Ending a Do Loop when Cell used in Vlookup is Blank

Tags: excel, vba, loops, do-loops

My goal is to take the data in column M of Excel #1 to Vlookup the name in the Excel #2 and fill in Excel #1's column C.

I can't get my loop to stop when I reach a blank cell in column M. Data starts at line 7.

```vb
Range("C7").Select

Do While Wroksheets("Sheet1").Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row <> ""
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
      "=VLOOKUP(RC[10],'excel.xlsx'!Table46[[column1]:[column7]],7,FALSE)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
Loop
```

Comment: `however, it won't stop` - because `.Row`, being the row number, is never `""`?

Comment: Makes sense, I guess what should be there instead? I came across that expression while I was doing research and it had worked for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a while loop here. The relative R1C1 formula allows you to write all formulas at once:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
  
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row

With ws.Range("M1:M" & LastRow)
  .FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[10],'excel.xlsx'!Table46[[column1]:[column7]],7,FALSE)"
End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much leosch! This worked, just one edit I had to make, the range for the column to run the vlookup in is C7:C. But other than that, works perfectly! Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

### Write Formulas to a Column Dynamically

```vb
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim rg As Range

With ws.Range("C7")
    Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = .EntireRow _
        .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
        .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data found
    Set rg = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
End With

rg.FormulaR1C1 _
    = "=VLOOKUP(RC[10],'excel.xlsx'!Table46[[column1]:[column7]],7,FALSE)"
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'm running into an issue with an error of "script out of range" in between the second and third lines. I put in the correct sheet name within my file and I guess it doesn't like that. Do you know of any issues within the coding if the sheet has more than one word and a "-"?

Comment: There is no special treatment, just double quotes e.g. `wb.Sheets("I Don't care what's my name")`. But the code may be in a different workbook, so you should reference the workbook with e.g. `Set wb = Workbooks("Whatever.xlsx")` or `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook`.